# Why are my pseudo classes not being detected as valid syntax by Sublime Text?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, sublimetext

I'm trying to take out all the underlines of my visited links on a website. In my CSS file, I put

```
nav li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And the term "visited" comes out as white text in Sublime Text, meaning the syntax is not recognized. I tried other pseudo classes too like

```
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}
```

And the "hover" is also not recognized. All my other CSS rules are working, by the way. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: It is not an issue or a bug, its just the color of the pseudo selector. Try a color theme.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you may want to check out my [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme). I have a lot of custom colors for CSS (and many other languages as well) in it. Your code will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyqN9.png) with it.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour by default.

You can solve this by [writing a custom color scheme](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html) or using an [existing color scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/color%20scheme) that colors the pseudo-class selectors the way you like.

There's no simple way to color the selectors. Extensive documentation on writing color schemes can be found [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html).